# Apache reverse proxy for external services

Tags: networking, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, port-forwarding

I'm not even sure this will make sense, so please bear with me.

Currently, ports 80 and 443 are used for my routers web interface.

I have an instance of Ubuntu 14.04 on my home VM that has LAMP installed, and I'm wondering if it's possible to set it up as a reverse proxy server using Apache in order to allow access to my sites that sit on that VM from port 80 and 443. My thinking is that the reverse proxy would then forward these ports to other ports that are open on my router.

All of my Ubuntu instances are within my home network and I don't have any external VPS' or servers. Is the above possible? If not, how would one go about setting something up so that anyone accessing ports 80 and 443 would be able to access my VM instance?

Comment: "Currently, ports 80 and 443 are used for my routers web interface." Internal facing or external facing? They should be **internal** ports 80 and 443, which means that someone accessing 443 or 80 from outside your network wouldn't hit them. In which case, ports 80 and 443 aren't really taken, with respect to the rest of the internet.

Comment: Which would mean that you can just set up static port forwarding rules directly on your router to forward external port 80 traffic to port 80 on the VM's IP, and 443 to 443 on the VM's IP. Since you only have one webserver, you shouldn't really need a reverse proxy at all. But if you really want one, you can use Apache for that (although personally I wouldn't recommend using Apache for any new projects; it's an old, broken technology with XML-y config files. `nginx` is better as a reverse proxy. That's just my informed opinion, though...).